# async.queue within a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, request

I am trying to create an async queue for an array of get requests to an api, i am just unsure how to combine and use the responses. Maybe my implementation is wrong since i am using async.queue inside a promise then function ?

Ultimately i would like to get results from first promise ->

use results of that first promise to create an array of get requests for the async.queue ->

then combine the results of all the get responses. I need to throttle the amount of requests that go out at a time due to API rate limit.

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    let arr = []
    rp.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
        let arrayID = response
        let q = async.queue((task, callback) => {
            request({
                method: "GET",
                url: url,
                qs: {
                    id: task.id
                }
            }, (error, response, body) => {
                arr.push(body)
                console.log(arr.length)
                // successfully gives me the response i want. im trying to push into an array with all of my responses,
                // but when i go to next then chain it is gone or if i try to return arr i get an empty []
            })
            callback()
        }, 3)
        for(var i = 0; i < arrayID.length; i++){
           q.push({ id : arrayID[i]} );
        }
        q.drain = function() {
            console.log('all items have been processed');
        }
        return arr
    })
    .then((responseArray) => {
        //empty array even though the length inside the queue said other wise, i know its a problem with async and sync actions but is there a way to make the promise chain and async queue play nice?
        res.json(responseArray)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, ended up having to wrap it in a promise and resolve the final array in q.drain()

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    rp.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
        let arrayID = response
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var q = async.queue((task, callback) => {
                request({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    qs: {
                        id:task.id,
                    },
                }, (error, response, body) => {
                    arr.push(body)
                    callback();
                })
            }, 2);

            q.drain = () => resolve(arr);
            q.push(arrayID);
        })

    })
    .then((response) => res.json(response))
    .catch((error) => res.json(error))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- To launch multiple async calls in parallel you can use `Promise.all()`
- To launch multiple async calls sequentially (i.e they depend on each other) you can return each promise and use its result inside a `then()` function

Code below:

```
app.get("/", (req,res)
  .then(function(firstResult)) {
    //You can use result of first promise here
    return Promise.all([
      //Create array of get request here
      //To also return firstResult just add it in the Promise.All array
    ]);
  })
  .then(function(allResults){
    //You can use results of all the get requests created in the previous then()
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    //Deal with any error that happened
  });
```

Comment: hey thanks, but initially when i tried it with a promise.all i was getting rate limited from the api iwas usini, so i needed something like async.queue or is there something i can tweak with Promise.all to mimic that? I need to be able to essentially do 10 in a promise.all then do another 10 then so on